# How to implement a executable JAR in Java

Tags: java, graphics, executable-jar

I made a game with Java. The game is running perfectly in Eclipse, but I want to export it to a executable JAR file. 
However, the JAR file is not working at all. (Double clicked, nothing happened. Not working in my friends computer as well.)

Is it because I don't have a main() function? If yes, what do I need in the main() function? 
Please tell me how to fix the problem. Many thanks.

/* my imports */

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

/* my class */

```
public class Breakout extends GraphicsProgram {

  public void init() {
   setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  public void run() {
   // while loop to run the game
  }

  // some methods ...

}
```

Comment: how are you running it in eclipse?

Comment: Is this an applet? If it is you will need to embed it in a webpage. It will be easier to make a desktop app if you use Swing.

Comment: If it's an `application` it needs `main` method with the right signature. If it's an `applet` then you do not need `main` most likely need `start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the application's entry point by making sure you have a `main` method in some class and specifying it in the JAR's manifest file.  Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe your game is based on Applets, Applets are meant to be embedded on a web page and be run in a web browser, if you want to run this as any other desktop application, then what you need to do is change the logic to use Frames, there are tutorials about Frames all over the internet, so serach around a bit and you will find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for answering my questions.

I found the solution.

The MAIN code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // new className().start(args);
    new Breakout().start(args);
}
```

Also, you need to edit the manifest file when you export the JAR.